# Android Marker does not work

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

My marker does not work. I dont know why. 
marker doesnt any work in onMapReady method.Works in onCreate.But its runing else . its print "hata1" and "hata2".
And when i create the new project does not import from /sdk/extras/../google_play/services. I get "cannot find file /settings.jar" error.So I dont want new project,too.

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.util.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap myMap;


    public static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(36.57, 36.17);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hata1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(myMap!=null) {
            Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(PERTH)
                    .title("Marker").visible(true));
            marker.showInfoWindow();

            myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(PERTH, 13));
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hata2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    @Override


    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap myMap) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private GoogleMap myMap;


public static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(36.57, 36.17);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    getHandleOnMap();
}
private void getHandleOnMap()
{
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap myMap) {
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(PERTH)
            .title("Hello"));
}
```

}

If you are facing any crashes or error , share detailed log

Comment: onMapReady method doesnt call ?

Comment: Try this in oncreate. You need to call getMapSync from oncreate

Comment: when i try on oncreate method application stopped

Comment: 12-16 12:22:03.701 21361-21361/com.example.samsun.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.samsun.myapplication.MapsActivity.getHandleOnMap(MapsActivity.java:39)

12-16 12:22:03.701 21361-21361/com.example.samsun.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.samsun.myapplication.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:33)

Comment: And Application has stopped

Comment: You are using FragmentActivity. I have edited code again for FragmentActivity. This will work now

Comment: SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

Comment: replace getChildFragmentManager() with getSuportFragmentMAnager(). Also, what version of Map aPi are you using. Log you shared was unclear. Please share detailed and clear crash log

Comment: Thank you so much Payal.Its Work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way ? because `onMapReady()` automatically once your `GoogleMap` is ready, and you get `GoogleMap` object to work on.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private GoogleMap myMap;

public static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(36.57, 36.17);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap myMap) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hata1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(myMap!=null) {
        Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(PERTH)
                .title("Marker").visible(true));
        marker.showInfoWindow();

        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(PERTH, 13));
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hata2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```